# How to explore Hindu texts

Tags: scripture, puranas, dharma

I am really eager to explore hindu texts for multitude of reasons. But, most of them are in sanskrit and I don't know the language. Hindi is my mothertongue, so I am confortable with devnagari but that's the closest I am to knowing the language itself. Some people suggest to read translations, but I just can't trust them.... I tried to read Shrimad Bhagwat gita by ISKCON but it just don't feel right, I felt the interpretations to be highly biased. Although I don't remember paticularly, there were some things written in it that I just can't imagine Lord Krishna saying.... the way other ways to salvation other than bhakti are downplayed just doesn't feel right. That's the reason I wanted to read the primary source itself, but there is the language barrier moreover even if I learn sanskrit, I don't know If I would be able to understand and interpret the knowledge given.... due to my ignorance I might misinterpret the texts....

so is there any alternative ways through which I can get unbiased, pure knowledge? any particular source on whom I can rely on for true, unbiased knowledge? if there isn't, can you please suggest some resource through which I can learn sanskrit on a level I can understand text?

Thanks a lot!
Om Namah Shivay

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to know a relaible, unbiased source through which I can get knowledge about hindu philosophy

Comment: Look out for gita press books. They are available online and have very authentic hindi translations

Comment: Also @CaptianPool Sanskrit swayam sikshak is a book which gives enough knowledge to understand Mahabharat/Ramayana, and the method is also easy to learn it takes less than an hour a day

Comment: thanks sbharti and Aditya Dwivedi, I would make sure to put these advices to use. thanks a lot :D